# How to remove or deactivate my windows 7 licence on one computer and use it on another

Tags: windows-7, license

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When installing Windows 7 or Vista, does the language, version, architecture (64-bit or 32-bit) or source (OEM, retail, or MSDN) matter?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/when-installing-windows-7-or-vista-does-the-language-version-architecture-64)

I want to remove my windows 7 genuine licence from one computer and install windows  7 on another computer using the same licence key.  I know the licence is somehow locked to the hardware of the original computer - but is there a way to uninstall the windows licence, so it can be re-used, and locked to new hardware?

(The original PC will go back to XP)

Answer (score 10):

If it was an OEM license (came with the computer from the manufacturer) you can't do this.  If it was a retail license (you bought it boxed from a retailer) then simply format the old computer, install it on the new computer.  If it comes up saying it may not be genuine, there will be a phone number you can call which will get you to a rep.  Explain to the rep and they will have you type in a new number.

Answer (score 2):

if it is a reatil copy, you are perfectly entitled to do this.

you may have to contact a Microsoft representative and explain the situation, should the activation fail.

while it is possible to [backup and restore the Windows 7 activation files](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/09/24/how-to-backup-and-restore-windows-7-and-server-2008-r2-activation-status-activate-offline-on-reinstall/), you may end up with a 'stained' license, MS don't like tampering with the product activation.

Answer (score 2):

Try activating the license on the new computer. If activation fails, call Microsoft Product Activation (866-542-3062) or Customer Service (800-642-7676) and tell them you changed the hardware on your computer and it deactivated itself. They will re-enable your activation without grilling you with any questions.