# Do I need to need to deactivate Windows before re-installing

Tags: windows-7, windows, license, oem, license-key

If I would like to reinstall Windows 7 on the same laptop as 64-bit instead of 32-bitusing the original key, would I need to deactivate Windows first using the process shown [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/124286/how-to-uninstall-your-windows-product-key-before-you-sell-your-pc/) or could I just reinstall and activate over the web or using something like [this](http://joshcellsoftwares.com/products/advancedtokensmanager/)?

Comment: Also see [How to remove or deactivate my windows 7 licence on one computer and use it on another](http://superuser.com/questions/77482/how-to-remove-or-deactivate-my-windows-7-licence-on-one-computer-and-use-it-on-a) and [how to deactivate windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/136946/how-to-deactivate-windows-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine.  There is no deactivation ability in Windows.  After installing, Windows will ask you to activate again.  Microsoft and Windows is smart enough to look at your hardware and see that it is the same and using the same key should work.  Absolute worst case, you would have to call them and tell them you are switching to 64 bit version.